# LINQ Dynamic Query with group by and string variable

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to create a dynamic query with LINQ-to-SQL and everything works except for one thing: group by. I looked at the other questions but haven't found a reason so far why it does not work.

I use `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` with the following query (that works):

```
int numberOfRankedItems = 3;

string minMaxChoice = "max";
string orderBy = "";
if (minMaxChoice == "max")
{
    orderBy = "queryGroup.Sum(row => row.POSITIONVALUE) descending";
} else if (minMaxChoice == "min")
{
    orderBy = "queryGroup.Sum(row => row.POSITIONVALUE) ascending";
}

string minMaxFeatureColumnName = "BRANDNAME";
string selectMinMaxFeature = "new { minMaxFeature = queryGroup.Key." + minMaxFeatureColumnName + ", sumPosition = queryGroup.Sum(row => row.POSITIONVALUE)}";

var query = (from tableRow in Context.xxx
                where /* some filters */
                group tableRow by tableRow.BRANDNAME into queryGroup
                orderby orderBy
                select selectMinMaxFeature).Take(numberOfRankedItems).ToList();
```

The use of variables for `orderby` and `select` works fine, but for `group by` not no matter what I try to replace with a variable. The query actually works if I e.g. use a variable instead of `tableRow.BRANDNAME` but the query returns the wrong result. The goal is to be able to set the column for the grouping dynamically.

Ideas?

Thanks

Edit: there seem to be multiple issues also with the other variables. So I generalize the question a bit: how can I generalize the following query in terms of

1. The column to group by
2. The column to order by + ASC or DESC
3. In the select statement the columnname of the first statement (BRANDNAME)

Here is the query:

```
var query = (from tableRow in ctx.xxx
                where /* filter */
                group tableRow by new { tableRow.BRANDNAME } into queryGroup
                orderby queryGroup.Sum(row => row.POSITIONVALUE) descending
                select new { minMaxFeature = queryGroup.Key.BRANDNAME, sumPosition = queryGroup.Sum(row => row.POSITIONVALUE) }).Take(numberOfRankedItems).ToList();
```

Would be great without expression trees ;)

Comment: If it works with the variable instead of the hardcoded value, but has different results, then it sounds like a matching issue.  How are the results different?  Can you tell what the grouping criteria is in both cases?  Is it grouping by the raw string value "BRANDNAME" and not associating that as a column name?  See the two examples about half way down the page here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results

Comment: I can;t find any evidence of query comprehension working with dynamic group by - can you show the code that doesn't work? Perhaps you aren't accomplishing what you think?

Comment: Please see my edits. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now elaborated a solution to the question:

The solution uses as before `using System.Linq.Dynamic;` allows now to set certain variables. In the end it returns a dictionary.

```
// set variables
int numberOfRankedItems;
if (queryData.NumberOfRankedItems != null)
{
    numberOfRankedItems = (int) queryData.NumberOfRankedItems;
} else
{
    numberOfRankedItems = 0;
}
string minMaxChoice = queryData.MinMaxChoice;
string minMaxFeatureColumnName = queryData.MinMaxFeatureColumnName;

string orderByPrompt = "";
if (minMaxChoice == "max")
{
    orderByPrompt = "it.Sum(POSITIONVALUE) descending";
} else if (minMaxChoice == "min")
{
    orderByPrompt = "it.Sum(POSITIONVALUE) ascending";
}

string groupByPrompt = queryData.MinMaxFeatureColumnName;

// execute query
IQueryable query = (from tableRow in Context.xxx
                        where /* some filters */
                        select tableRow).
                        GroupBy(groupByPrompt, "it").
                        OrderBy(orderByPrompt).
                        Select("new (it.Key as minMaxFeature, it.Sum(POSITIONVALUE) as sumPosition)").
                        Take(numberOfRankedItems);

// create response dictionary
Dictionary<int?, Dictionary<string, int?>> response = new Dictionary<int?, Dictionary<string, int?>>();
int count = 1;
foreach (dynamic item in query)
{
    string minMaxFeatureReturn = item.GetType().GetProperty("minMaxFeature").GetValue(item);
    int? sumPositionReturn = item.GetType().GetProperty("sumPosition").GetValue(item);
    response[count] = new Dictionary<string, int?>() { { minMaxFeatureReturn, sumPositionReturn } };
    count++;
}            
return response;
```